# Generic function stream.map

Tags: java, function, generics, lambda, java-stream

I currently have a class test which transforms a stream to a stream of same type.

```
class Test {
    private Function<A1, A1> a1Transform;
    private Function<A2, A2> a2Transform;

    public <T extends A> Stream<T> transform(Stream<T> input) {
        return input
            .filter(o -> o instanceof A1)
            .map(A1.class::cast)
            .map(a1Transform);
    }
}
```

The code doesn't compile unless

1. I make the return type `Stream<? super T>` or
2. I add a `.map(o -> (T) o)` to cast it back to T.

Is either of the solutions any good. What would be a better way to approach this problem.

Comment: After `map(A1.class::cast)`, the actual type of the stream is `Stream<A1>`. The return type `Stream<T>` is probably wrong, but you need to tell us more about what you're trying to do before we can tell you what the correct change to the code is.

Comment: The body of `transform` seems to work only with `Stream<A1>` anyway, so why not declare it as `Stream<A1> transform(Stream<A1> input)`? Is the `filter`-step essential, or did you want to pass a `Function<A, A>` as second parameter to `transform`?

Comment: The A1 is just an example. I could have an ```if``` loop to check which transform to apply.

Comment: Use case: I have a collection of transforms on objects implementing an interface. Like A1, A2, A3 all implementing interface A. Now based on the type of objects in the stream I want to apply the appropriate transform and then return the resulting stream. @Radiodef

Comment: The input is expected to have same type as output stream.
Example:Input Stream<A1> and I would expect the return to be Stream<A1> or Input Stream<A2> and I would expect the return to be Stream<A2>. So, in the above question, the input would be Stream<A1> I cast it to A1, then apply a1Transform and then again cast it to A1

Comment: If you're calling it with a `Stream<A1>` and using a transform that returns `A1` then you don't need to filter or cast anything. If you're calling it with a `Stream<A>` and you need it to figure out whether it actually contains `A1`, `A2`, etc. at run-time, then generics aren't going to work. It's not clear what you're actually trying to do here, the example you give doesn't fully reflect the requirements.

Answer (score 1):

If `A1`, `A2`, etc. have a common supertype `A`, then you could change the method to something like the following:

```
public Stream<A> transform(Stream<?> input) {
    return input.filter(o -> o instanceof A1)
                .map(o -> (A1) o)
                .map(a1Transform)
                .map(o -> (A) o);
}
```

There's no way for a method to return, say, *either* `Stream<A1>`, *or* `Stream<A2>`, *or* `Stream<A3>`, etc. The best you can do is like the above, where you return a `Stream<A>`, or you could return a `Stream<? extends A>`.

If it's really important to return a stream with the exact type of the elements, then you could use something like the visitor pattern, and pass the visitor in to the method instead of returning the stream directly.

Another possible way could be for the caller to pass a `Class` in to the method:

```
public <T extends A> Stream<T> transform(Stream<?> input, Class<T> type) {
    return input...
                ...
                ...
                .map(type::cast);
}
```

However, running in to this kind of problem is usually an indication that you need to redesign something. In general, in object-oriented design, code which is external to your API should not be concerned with having specific types of objects.